# Is there has a preg that can filter all js script in php？

Tags: php, preg-match

I need filter all Js script in php，i have a preg `/<[^>]*?>.*?<\/>/si`，but it does not work well. Is there has a good preg that can filter all js script in php？

Comment: This question is very ambiguous, but it sounds like you're attempting to parse HTML with RegExps, please don't, use the DomDocument class instead to parse the document for you, you can then easily remove all script tags or tags with certain attributes, before exporting it back to a string. It will be safer, easier and more maintainable.

Comment: Have you considered that JavaScript may be inlined as well?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you edited your question and described exactly what you are trying to do. An example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This script will remove all script elements as well any any inline scripts in 'onload' or 'onclick' handlers:

```
$tags = <<<'EOT'
<body onload="alert('onload');">
<div onclick="alert('onclick');">
    <script>alert('script');</script>
    <h1 onclick="alert('onclick');">heading</h1>
    content
</div>
<script>var that = this;</script>
<p>paragraph</p>
</body>
EOT;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($tags);

$scripts = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
// Loop through backwards otherwise item($i) will change
for ($i = $scripts->length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
  $script = $scripts->item($i);
  $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}

// Not a built-in class
// see comments on http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php
$rec = new DOMNodeRecursiveIterator($doc->getElementsByTagName('*'));
foreach ($rec as $node) {
  if ($node->nodeType === 1) {
    $node->removeAttribute('onload');
    $node->removeAttribute('onclick');
  }
}

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
echo $doc->saveHTML($body);
```

DOMDocument::loadHTML will parse the string `$tags` and create a DOMDocument object. In doing so, it creates a valid HTML document, so will add in a doctype, a `<html>` tag and a `<body>` tag if they are not already present. The first loop removes all `<script>` elements from the document. The second loop traverses the DOM recursively and removes all 'onload' and 'onclick' inline handlers.

If you are reading a complete document (rather than just the `<body>` as in my example), the bottom lines can be simplified to `echo $doc->saveHTML();`.

Output:

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1>heading</h1>
    content
</div>
<p>paragraph</p>
```

Obviously this isn't going to be bulletproof (for example, there may be other attributes that you would like to remove) but it might be good enough for what you need. DOMDocument is capable of parsing badly formed HTML so it is likely to be a lot more flexible than any solution that relies on regular expressions.

Comment: `<body onload="alert('you may have overlooked something');">`

Comment: @Jack that's a fair point. I've edited to show how you might go about removing those kinds of attributes as well.

Comment: Might I also suggest that since he wants to remove all scripts start by running `getElementsByTagName('script')` and foreach result get the parent, then remove the script tag (`$obj->parentNode->removeChild($obj);`). Avoids some sneaky person putting a script tag inside a div to hide it on the page `<body><div><script>alert('missed me')</script></div></body>`

Comment: @scragar thanks for your suggestion. I've edited the code to make it more robust. Any further comments would be appreciated.